# How to present a plot and then return to cmd prompt

Tags: windows-xp, gnuplot

I have a data file, and a gnu file, in which my plotting commands are.

How can I produce a plot in gnuplot, in a way that I call gnuplot giving it a name of the gnu file ... it gives me the window with a plot ... and after I close it, it returns me not to gnuplot command prompt, but to cmd (windows cmd.exe) command prompt ?

Answer (score 0):

There's 3 solutions for this problem (for producing persistent plots) when starting gnuplot from a script (using `gnuplot script.gnuplot`).

- Use a `pause -1` at the end of your gnuplot script (after the plot), such that a user needs to press enter before gnuplot destroys the window with the plot
- Use `gnuplot script.gnuplot -` to go into gnuplot's interactive mode after the script has completed
- Use the `-persist` command line option to create a persistent plot window